# printing fibonacci series using recursion in c++

Tags: c++, recursion, fibonacci

I just started learning c++ by myself. I am trying to practice recusion now. I want to print all n(input by user) fibonacci numbers using recursion, but it does not work. Could you help me? Thank you!!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int fibonacci(int n)
{   
    if (n==1)
    {
        return 1;
        cout<<1<<" ";
    }   
    else if (n==2)
    {
        return 1;
        cout<<1<<" ";
    }
    else
    {
        return (fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2));
        cout<<fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)<<" ";
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    fibonacci(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect code after `return` to do?

Comment: Code *after* a return **will not execute**. After all, you *returned* to the calling function.

Comment: you want result, so : `cout << fibonacci(n);`

Comment: Did you write this all by yourself? If yes, do strengthen your basics by getting a book or something. Else, write it yourself.

Comment: @marcin_j i tried, it does not work...

Comment: @Ranveer yes, i wrote it all by myself, i just started learning c++ by myself now.

Comment: @Bathsheba i know how to do it in a for loop, i am trying to practice recursion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [Rosetta Code page for Fibonacci](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence), you see that `F(0) == 0` and `F(1) == 1`.

```
int fibonacci(int n)
{   

    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }   
    else if (n == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
    }

    return fib;
}
```

In this case, you have a function that will calculate the fibonacci number at a specific position, right?

So now you need to calculate them and then print them:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    if (n < 0)
    {
        return -1; // This means there was an error
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cout << fibonacci(i) << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that this is *not the most efficient way to do it at all*, but it kinda helps you understand how recursion works.

Comment: And then, you can search what memoization means.

Comment: Well, [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) is really just a fancy way of saying "don't calculate the same thing twice".

Answer (score 3):

**No need for cout in Fibonacci function, only cout by loop in int main()... also change IF 
condition in Fibonacci function to <=0 otherwise it will give you a segmentation fault (error)**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int fibonacci(int n)
{   
    if (n<=0)
    {
        return 0;
    //    cout<<1<<" ";
    }   
    else if (n==1)
    {
        return 1;
    //    cout<<1<<" ";
    }
    else
    {
        return (fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2));
    //   cout<<fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)<<" ";
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
    cout << fibonacci(x) << " ";
    cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: n<=0 is necessary because it returns otherwise -1 + -2 = -3 which produces segmentation fault ...

Comment: also u r calling cout after return... so it wont b executed

Answer (score 2):

Even if you place `cout` before your return statement, your code will not give you the fibonacci series in the right order. Let's say you ask for `fibonacci(7)`. It will print all the intermediate computations  for `fibonacci(6)`, and then it will print all 1's for `fibonacci(5)`.

Comment: It's even more complex, as the "cout" lines also trigger the recursion.